# How to change the width and height of a textarea according to the size of its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way for the height and width of a textarea to change according to its content? The scrollbar is no needed.

HTML:

```
<td valign="top" width="100%">
    <textarea class="msg"> everything is good.. </textarea>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.msg{
    padding:20px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
    height:auto;
    line-height:30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    white-space:normal;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    resize:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason your not using a `<Div>` ?    it will increase height and width based on it's content.

Comment: Thanks. you're right.

Comment: Wait, @Nikerym is correct. Why do you want a readonly textarea if you can make it a div? Tables also can have divs inside.

Comment: No (i think!). I want to see content. keep in mind scrollbar is no needed.

Comment: I know a div changes, but its content does not change dynamically. Almost like a messenger app.

Comment: You can hide the scrollbars on the div using `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` in your CSS and setting the value to `hidden`  you can change a div's content dynamically using Javascript,  a Textarea set to Readonly is basically a less functional div. unless you plan to dynamically remove the readonly,  and let people modify text then i honestly don't see a reason to use textarea over div in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`scrollWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth) and [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) to update the style of your element to match its content's dimensions.

> The **Element.scrollWidth** read–only property returns either the width in pixels of the content of an element or the width of the element itself, whichever is greater. If the element is wider than its content area (for example, if there are scroll bars for scrolling through the content), the scrollWidth is larger than the clientWidth.
>
> The **Element.scrollHeight** read-only attribute is a measurement of the height of an element's content, including content not visible on the screen due to overflow. The scrollHeight value is equal to the minimum clientHeight the element would require in order to fit all the content in the viewpoint without using a vertical scrollbar. It includes the element padding but not its margin.

Using jQuery:

```
var msg = $('.msg');
msg.css('width',  msg[0].scrollWidth);
msg.css('height', msg[0].scrollHeight);
```

However, it doesn't seem to shrink back when the content becomes smaller.

We can make it shrink by forcing a smaller size before checking the dimensions, essentially resetting the minimum possible size.

```
msg.css('width',  1);
msg.css('height', 1);
msg.css('width',  msg[0].scrollWidth);
msg.css('height', msg[0].scrollHeight);
```

Demo in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/86fecx6j/1/).